# wordpress css image link

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

Hello—I am trying (and failing miserably) to make these Social Media icons in the upper-right of the navigation of my Wordpress blog (www.doublecrossxx.com) clickable. I managed to add the code to get them properly placed but I am unable to figure out how to create a clickable area around the image.

```
#access {

background: black;
background-image: url("http://doublecrossxx.com/images/sm_dcxx.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 599pt 2pt;
height: 27px;
width: 23px;
display: inline-block;

    float: left;

    margin: 0;

    width: 845px;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you want the `margin` attribute, to increase the clickable area. I am not sure whether this will work with the 'sprite' approach - but try it! `:)`

Comment: Use links instead of setting the background image of that entire div.

Comment: Thank you halfer and Jrod. Jrod, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "use links"? I apologize but I'm a little new to customizing Wordpress themes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any actual links (`<a>`'s);for people to click on. You just have a background image applied to your #access div.

So, you will have to add links in some way to your #access div. I can't see your theme files, but if I had to *guess*, look in a file called **header.php**. That usually is what is used to build the top part of a wordpress page.

You should be able to find the #access div pretty quickly, and can add links, like this:

```
<div id="access">
   <!-- some php stuff for your menu -->
   <a id="fb_link" href="(link to facebook)"></a>
   <a id="twitter_link" href="(link to twitter)"></a>
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS (presumably style.css), use that image as a background to those two links instead of #access:

```
#fb_link, #twitter_link {
    background: url("images/sm_dcxx.jpg") no-repeat top left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
 }
#twitter_link {
    background-position: top -25px;
 }
```

(You will have to adjust the 25px amount, that was just a guess on my part)

The downside of this technique is that you will have to manually alter header.php if you ever need to change the links. Not a big deal, but you should be aware of it.

Also, I noticed that your image URL was like this:

http://doublecrossxx.com/images/sm_dcxx.jpg

Which tells me you created a folder at the top level of your wordpress install called /images/. You shouldn't do that. Any and all files you add to your WP install should at the very least be placed in /wp-content/. Images that are part of your presentation (like the one in question here) should *definitely* be in your theme folder. In my CSS above, I used a relative link to an images folder that sits next to the CSS file.

Comment: Thank you so much chipcullen! I am trying to make it work right now. I really appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I've created you a js fiddle that will allow your links to be clickable, let me know if you have any problems with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/trickeedickee/PYTnm/

Comment: Thanks so much trickeedickee! I'm going to give it a try. I really appreciate you doing that!